# Matching from multiple relationships

Tags: sqlite, many-to-many

I have a "posts" table. Each post record can have one or more tags.
 If I store the tags into a single column, as a comma delimited string, I can easily find the posts that have tag "Abc" and tag "Def", or even do partial matching.

I'm using sqlite and a "FTS" table with this method and it works fine, but someone told me that it's a bad practice and I should store the tags in a different table and use JOINs.
If I store the tags in a different table and create a relationship between these 2 tables, how do I find posts with both tag "Abc" and tag "Def" in a single query? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed bad design practice.

You will get slow performance since you need to do string operations on the column value to seperate the tags. So indexes can't be used. And it is against the normalization rules of database design.

A better design would be

```
tags table
----------
id
name


posts table
-----------
id
title
body
...


post_tags table
---------------
post_id
tag_id
```

To get all posts have both tags do

```
select p.id, p.title, p.body
from posts p
join post_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
join tags t on pt.tag_id = t.id
where t.name in ('abc','def')
group by p.id, p.title, p.body
having count(distinct t.id) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to normalize your database, I would definitly split this information into multiple tables. I have written up a schema and some example queries showing how you could pull the data out. You can view this here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48ebb/15

Basically you would have 3 tables:

- POST Table: contains the post information.
- POSTTAGS Table: Is the joining table containing the IDs from the POST table and the TAG table
- TAG Table: contains the tag information

In this way you never store the same tag information twice.

Lastly here is a sample query from the sqlfiddle posted above:

```
-- find all posts with the tags associated with them
SELECT DISTINCT POST.*, GROUP_CONCAT(tagName SEPARATOR ', ') AS associatedTags
FROM POST
   INNER JOIN POSTTAGS ON POST.postId = POSTTAGS.postId
   INNER JOIN TAG ON TAG.tagId = POSTTAGS.tagId
```